# Pretty print JSON to R console?

Tags: r, json

Is there a way to pretty-print JSON in the R console?

I'm trying to read JSON in the R console and it would be much easier if it printed already formatted/indented. I have tried two using `cat()` and that observed the new line characters, but not indentation.

Example JSON:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)
require(RJSONIO)

df <- data.frame(name=c("Holdingcompany","Holdingcompany","company1","company1","company2","company2"),children=c("company1","company2","company4","company3","company5","company6"),info=c("text1","text2","text3","text5","othertext","other_text"),percentage=c("100%","100%","60%","75%","80%","70%"))

makeList<-function(x){
  if(ncol(x)>2){
    listSplit<-split(x[-1],x[1],drop=T)
    lapply(names(listSplit),function(y){list(name=y,children=makeList(listSplit[[y]]))})
  }else{
    lapply(seq(nrow(x[1])),function(y){list(name=x[,1][y],Percentage=x[,2][y])})
  }
}

# This provides unformatted JSON
makeList(df) %>% toJSON

# This shows new lines, but not indentation
makeList(df) %>% toJSON %>% cat
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `prettify()` function from `jsonlite`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(jsonlite)

makeList(df) %>% 
  toJSON %>% 
  prettify()

[
    {
        "name": "company1",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "company3",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "text5",
                        "Percentage": "75%"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "company4",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "text3",
                        "Percentage": "60%"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
...
```